# To get Calculate Time Worked

Tags: c#

I currently build a system there is a part to manage Employee timein and timeout, i want to calculate this

```
 ***night shift (Must Work 8 Hr)***
  startTime- 10.00 PM   
  endTime- 06.00 AM
```

So I want to calculate actually worked hours for that date (timein  - timeout). What I have done is

```
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));
```

Output :16:00

What I want is 8:00

Eg 2

startTime- 10.00 PM
   endTime- 05.00 AM

Out Put : 7:00

How can i done this?

Comment: You need to have a date in the start and end times as well as the time, not *just* a time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `date` with `time` as well to exact hours between two times. As you would be having different dates in the time. Assume shift starts at 18 march, 2013 at 10:00PM and ends 19 march, 2013 5:00AM

Comment: Adil Sorry I can't understand what u say can u please Explain using a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`Timespan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) like;

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2008, 01, 02, 23, 30, 00);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2008, 01, 03, 06, 30, 00);

TimeSpan duration = b - a;

Console.WriteLine(duration);
```

Output will be

```
07:00:00
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/uOg8zz).

> A TimeSpan object represents a time interval (duration of time or
>   elapsed time) that is measured as a positive or negative number of
>   days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractions of a second.

Comment: @pradeep just cannot do this every time, only when the endTime is smaller than start time (time spans through the midnight)

Comment: I think he is already using Timespan; I reckon the error is how he constructs the original dates.